# How to reference static properties on `this.constructor` inside base class code?

Tags: javascript, generics, typescript

I have TypeScript (JavaScript) class like this:

```
import * as React from 'react'

export default
class StyleableComponent<PROPS, STATE> extends React.Component<PROPS, STATE> {
    protected classes: any
    static style: any

    someMethod() {
        const ctor = this.constructor
        console.log(this.constructor.style)
    }
}
```

and TypeScript throws this error:

```
ERROR in ./src/StyleableComponent.ts
(11,38): error TS2339: Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Function'.
```

But, obviously, you can see that `static style: any` is declared in the class definition.

So, how do we work with `this.constructor` properly? Note, `this.constructor` can be the constructor of a class that extends `StyleableComponent`, so `this.constructor` may not be `=== StyleableComponent`, but it should have the `style` property because it extends from `StyleableComponent`.

For example,

```
interface P {...}
interface S {...}
class Foo extends StyleableComponent<P,S> {...}

console.log(new Foo)
```

^ `this.constructor` will be `Foo`, and the `StyleableComponent` class needs to look at `Foo.style`.

So how do I do this? Do I need to use a extra template type parameter somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Static Property V.S Instance Property Inheritance

If you want read static property from subclass,you can do it with 3 ways.for more details you can see **Test** section.

- because `Object.getPrototypeOf(..)`'s return type is `any`, so you can access style directly,for example:

  ```
  someMethod() {        
    let style = Object.getPrototypeOf(this).constructor.style;          
  }
  ```
- because `this.constructor`'s return type is a `Function`, so you must assign it to a `any` variable at first,for example:

  ```
  someMethod() {        
    let cotr:any=this.constructor;
    let style = cotr.style;          
  }
  ```
- because `Function` is an interface you can expand it in typescript,for example:

  ```
  declare global{
    interface Function{
      style:any;
    }
  }

  someMethod() {        
    return this.constructor.style;         
  }
  ```

and you can also do it with replace static property with instance property instead.if you want read subclass `style` property you must define the property on constructor,then the subclass can choose define its style by pass the `style` to the superclass or not at all.for example:

```
constructor(protected style:any="default"){
}
```

the interesting is that the subclass behavior are all the same except the `style` property.In design view, if you use the static style properties you must define another subclass to achieve it,this will tends to many subclass with diff styles.but when use instance property `style`,you can  do it by pass the `style` with optional for different `style` only.for example:

```
let bar=new Bar();//use parent's style
let baz=new Bar(null,null,"baz");//use it owned style
```

and you can also reject others to pass their style by pass the `style` in constructor of the subclass.for example:

```
constructor(){
  super("style");
}
```

### Tests

```
import * as React from 'react';
declare global {
    interface Function {
        style: any
    }
}
describe('static inheritance', () => {

    class StyleableComponent<P, S> extends React.Component<P, S> {
        protected classes: any;
        static style: any;

        constructor(props?: P, context?: any, public style: any = "default") {
            super(props, context);
        }

        someMethod() {
            //dangerous if subclass not define static style property
            //todo:the 1st approach
            // let style = Object.getPrototypeOf(this).constructor.style;
            // return style;
            //todo:the 2nd approach
            // let cotr: any = this.constructor;
            // return cotr.style;
            //todo:the 3nd approach,you must declare style in Function interface
            return this.constructor.style;
        }
    }


    class Foo extends StyleableComponent<any, any> {
        static style = "foo";

        constructor(props?: any, context?: any) {
            super(props, context, Foo.style);
        }
    }

    class Bar extends StyleableComponent<any, any> {
    }

    test('access style from subclass', function () {
        let foo = new Foo();

        expect(foo.someMethod()).toBe(Foo.style);
    });


    test('return undefined if subclass not define style', function () {
        let bar = new Bar();

        expect(bar.someMethod()).toBeUndefined();
    });

    test('replace static style with instance property', function () {
        let foo = new Foo();
        let bar = new Bar();
        let baz = new Bar(null, null, "baz");

        expect(foo.style).toBe("foo");
        expect(bar.style).toBe("default");
        expect(baz.style).toBe("baz");
    });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `new.target` only works in the constructor. :{ Changing my question to reflect that.

Comment: @trusktr sir,if you accept `new.target`,why don't to give a try to access class properties directly via class?e.g:`StyleableComponent.style`.

Comment: By design, the static `style` property needs to be read from the subclass, not the StyleableComponent class. Subclasses define a `style` object, then the base class applies that style for all instances of the subclass, and it need to look at `subclass.style` to get the style definition.

Comment: @trusktr I have updated my answer,I wish you to give some feedback about my new answer.I'm not good at english,so I wish you understand what I  said.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the answer! I can understand it just fine. :}